# Utility to quickly convert a sequence of images to an animated GIF

Tags: graphics, gif, animated-gif

Is there a simple utility to quickly convert a sequence of images (I have 3) to an animated GIF with some settings, like time delay? I need to convert a couple of such sequences with the same settings.

Comment: Which operating system should the utility run on ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[UnFREEz](http://www.whitsoftdev.com/unfreez/)** is a high-speed Windows application that will take any number of images, saved as separate GIF files, and create a single animated GIF from those images.

[image]

*UnFREEz is freeware and portable, it doesn't require installation.*

Answer (score 2):

You can use the convert utility which is part of ImageMagick ( http://www.imagemagick.org/ )

Answer (score 2):

If you want to automate this process, then [gifsicle](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/). It's also useful for [reducing size of GIFs](http://imageoptim.com).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do this with this software:

http://www.banner-maker.net/